# How To Automate Text from a C# Textbox to a Div Textbox in a website

Tags: c#, webdriver, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

So I am simply making my life easier as a Youtuber content Creator by being able to post my own work onto Reddit Website. There is a time limit on how often I can Post here:https://www.reddit.com/submit. I am trying to automate the text box with text from a Textbox in C# every So often using a amount of times. I have tried several different Idea's since I'm using the Chromium WebBrowser under CefSharp. Here is a link to my full project so you can see for yourself: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jR5xRGYGZuLG_rE5fCH4RbWEd2WeioFa?usp=sharing

I need help in the ability to Enter any text I have in my Textbox in Form 1, and when I Press Start, it opens the submit location (Plan on doing a auto sign in later) and then paste or "Automate" the typing of what I have in my Text Box onto the Text Box on the Website. How Can I do this? I need help!

[Photo 1 of what my code in C# Works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrbRW.png)

[Photo 2 of what my code in C# Works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khycq.png)

Comment: Does Reddit have a public API? That would be preferable to trying to load their website in a browser.

Comment: @amaitland they have it here: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/ but i do not know how to implement this into my program.

Comment: Your less likely to be banned for being a bit if you use their official API.

Comment: @amaitland the thing is, i don't know how to implement API's in C# or even at all. Never had to use an API.

Comment: Thirty seconds of searching brings up https://github.com/sirkris/Reddit.NET which looks like a an ideal solution.